# Angular Ui bootsrap datepicker not working

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-bootstrap

i've a card view of a doctor with button "book appointment" button which pops up a datepicker.

i've been trying to apply angular ui bootstrap datepicker but its not working.

however I was able to apply

```
<datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="false"></datepicker>
```

I have checked other questions in stackoverflow about the same issue but nothing seems to work. my doubt is that i am not using the correct bootstrap js or angular js.

**EDIT :**
Updated plunker . I m not getting the drop down bootstrap datepicker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/uvYFVx?p=preview

Comment: I know it sounds obvious but have you looked at the Plunker example from the Angular Bootstrap page - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Comment: can you at least provide a working plunker? that sample doesn't load the angular components, it loads your Readme.md file.

Comment: you forgot to add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>` in the `<head>`

Comment: After renaming Main.html to index.html (so that plnkr will open the file by default) I can click the book button, the modal opens and you can select a date. Sure, the styling seems to have some problems, and you are not closing the modal correctly after selecting a date, but other than that it seems to work. Hm?

Comment: @Claies i have updated the plunker and is working now, thanks to ippi. i am not able to get the drop down bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: where is the controller for the modal? you have `controller: ModalInstanceCtrl` defined, but it's not a file that exists.  The missing controller is causing a Type Error in the modal. when Angular Datepicker goes to look for an undefined property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `open` method inside Modal Controller to

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened = true;
};
```

Also include the `dateOptions` object in your Modal controller or define the `init-date` attribute on input element

```
$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
};
```

See the working example here http://plnkr.co/edit/Ju3ShB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but why you added $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();